# Angular4 modules: Best practices

Tags: angular, angular-module

I've working on a bigger project in Angular 4.3.6 and I'm wondering what is the best way to split different navigation items into modules. All modules are lazy loaded.

Navigation is like (excerpt)

- Administration

  - Personal settings

    - My Profile
    - Change Password
    - Preferences
    - Reports
  - Application Settings

    - Basic Settings
    - Advanced Settings
    - Filters
    - Views
  - User Management

    - create user
    - list users

I'm curious what would the best way to seperate this into modules.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I don't get the point, the question is limited to a specific problem (how to seperate into modules) and this is the only question I have. I've provided an Example and want to know what would be the best way to implement that.

Answer (score 3):

This is a subjective question and there is no perfect answer, in my view the best way to do this is to separate by concern. Think it like this, if you load your whole application at once there will be routes and components that the user will never access. Therefore your application will be slow because it has to load a lot of stuff the user will never use. Ex: there is no point in loading a registration component every time if the user is only gonna register once in your application. So try to group the modules by things the user may use together, so if he go to screen A he is very likely to go to screen B so it makes sense to put then in the same module and lazy load it. Also try to create a shared module so you can put what is common to more than one module to avoid duplication. As well as try to keep your modules as small as possible.